# ros::ok() and ros::isShutingDown() and thread

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roscore, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used ros::ok and ros::isShuttingDown inside a thread to find out if the user closed roscore in the terminal by pressing Cnrl+C. However, when I do that, the values of those to function do not change, and threads keep running.

for more detail please see the question on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900372/stdthread-and-rosok-do-not-work-in-ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403505/ros::ok()-and-ros::isshutingdown()-and-thread/) by [farhad-bat](https://answers.ros.org/users/108560/farhad-bat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. You can see it on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900372/stdthread-and-rosok-do-not-work-in-ros/72901206#72901206

---

Originally posted by [farhad-bat](https://answers.ros.org/users/108560/farhad-bat/) with karma: 13 on 2022-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1